# How to analyze a table using DBMS_STATS package in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, oracle11g

Here's the code I'm working on:

```
begin
    DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS (ownname => 'appdata' , 
    tabname => 'TRANSACTIONS',
    cascade => true, 
    estimate_percent => DBMS_STATS.AUTO_SAMPLE_SIZE,
    method_opt=>'for all indexed columns size 1', 
    granularity => 'ALL', 
    degree => 1);
end;
```

After executing the code, `PL/SQL procedure successfully completed` is displayed.

How to view the statistics for the particular table, analyzed by DBMS_STATS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may see information in `DBA_TABLES`

```
SELECT * 
FROM DBA_TABLES where table_name='TRANSACTIONS';
```

e.g. Column `LAST_ANALYZED` shows when it was last analyzed.

There are also information column by column in

```
SELECT * FROM all_tab_columns where table_name='TRANSACTIONS';
```

where you could find min value, max value, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)